# Dataframe tolist adds [] or the dataframe reads header while going through a for loop. How can I get the list to work in the for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, alteryx

I'm using an import from an Alteryx data flow, which is a single column that contains the following integer format:

[image]

Reading the data in from alteryx converts it to a dataframe automatically.

```
searches = Alteryx.read("dataimport")

SUCCESS: reading input data "dataimport"
      RxNorm_Id
0            99
1           161
2           167
3           168
4           197
...         ...
6711    2562541
6712    2565823
6713    2566308
6714    2566416
6715    2571104
```

I have a for loop that looks through URL's and replaces a segment with the search.

```
for search in searches:
    print(f"Scraping {search}")
    url = f"https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/rxcui/{search}/historystatus.json?caller=RxNav"
    print(url)
```

When I attempt to run the data through the loop it starts with the header name first

Scraping RxNorm_Id
https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/rxcui/**RxNorm_Id**/historystatus.json?caller=RxNav

I'm not exactly sure why it uses the header first, but obviously it causes an error because the search doesn't exist.

If I try to change the dataframe to a list, it wraps each item in a square bracket.  Such as:

```
Info: Python (2): [[99], [161], [167], [168], [197], [272], [281], [376]]


searches = searches.values.tolist()

Scraping [99]
https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/rxcui/[99]/historystatus.json?caller=RxNav
```

If I hardcode searches as [99,161,167,168,197,272,281,376] my loop works without an issue.

How can I get the initial data frame in that format?  Or how can I get the tolist function to not wrap each number in square brackets.

I understand my data source is secure and using Alteryx prevents me from replicating the data source.  But, this should be enough information to solve the issue.

Below is my entire code trimmed for easily reproducible:

```
    from ayx import Alteryx
    from numpy import dtype
    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    
    searches = Alteryx.read("dataimport")
#    searches = searches.values.tolist()
    
    
#    for search in searches: attempt for the tolist() function
    for search in [searches]:
        print(f"Scraping {search}")
        url = f"https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/rxcui/{search}/historystatus.json?caller=RxNav"

        print(url)
        data = s.get(url,headers=headers).json()      #results from second redirect
        print(data)
        a = data['rxcuiStatusHistory']['definitionalFeatures']
        b = data['rxcuiStatusHistory']['attributes']
        print(b)
        rxcui = b['rxcui']
        name = b['name']
        print(rxcui)
        print(name)
    
        try: 
            baserxcui = a['ingredientAndStrength'][0]['baseRxcui']
            basename = a['ingredientAndStrength'][0]['baseName']
            print(baserxcui)
            print(basename)
        except KeyError:
            baserxcui = rxcui
            basename = name
            print(baserxcui)
            print(basename)
    
        try:  
            bossrxcui = a['ingredientAndStrength'][0]['bossRxcui']
            bossname = a['ingredientAndStrength'][0]['bossName']
            print(bossrxcui)
            print(bossname)
        except KeyError:
            bossrxcui = rxcui
            bossname = name
            print(bossrxcui)
            print(bossname)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take the first item inside search since search is a list. So your code then becomes something like this:

```
for search in searches:
    print(f"Scraping {search[0]}")
    url = f"https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/rxcui/{search[0]}/historystatus.json?caller=RxNav"
    print(url)
```

Or you can simple just change

```
searches = searches.values.tolist()
```

to

```
searches = [i[0] for i in searches.values.tolist()]
```

Comment: This should work, but it doesn't because the format of the list is invalid for the url when using the tolist() function.

Comment: I made some errors in my first answer. Please check again.

Comment: Thank you Emmanuel, the second solution worked.  Changing the index to 1 on the first solution did the trick, but I also had to do for search in [searches]..  either way, you got me there and I appreciate it.